# Netbeans Git compared to Github Client

Tags: netbeans, version-control, github, versioning

I'm fairly new to git and version control. So I see Netbeans has the git options Commit and Clone. Are there any disadvantages of using the built in git controls in netbeans versus the actual windows github client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no advantage or disadvantage. They both perform the same task. If you are doing your task in Netbeans, then I would suggest you to go with Netbeans git stuff.

But in general, using git from the commandline is a good way of learning the basics for a newbie and then go on and use the GUI stuffs once one is comfortable.